# next() isn't skipping over the rest of the middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm very much a newbie to the whole express routing logic (and node and js for that matter). But I have problem that I can't seem to trace, but I think I understand the context of it. Well now, that didn't make a lot of sense, here it goes anyway.

I'm trying to skip through middleware conditionally based on data in the req.query and it renders the intended form page fine except for the fact that I get 'Cannot send header twice ...' in the console from the previous middleware, which i thought i skipped.

From what I can gather next() should get me to the next middleware instantly and skip the rest of the block entirely (kind of like how a `return` kicks you out of a function). Is this not correct?

path: localhost:3000/JohnnyBoy?action=form

```
    router.get('/:name/', function(req, res, next) {

      if(req.query.action !== 'view') { next(); };

      console.log('Why am I seeing this in the console?');

      res.render('first', { 
        title: req.params.name 
        });
    });

    router.get('/:name/', function(req, res, next) {

        res.render('form', {  
                  title: req.params.name + ' This is a form page', 
                  formFields: fields.userPostFields()
                  });
    });
```

Comment: Side note: The block attached to a control-flow statement (like `if`) terminates itself; no `;` is required after it. *(Having it there only works because empty statements are valid in JavaScript.)*

Comment: ok, thanks good to know. Still finding my form (no pun intended) here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `return;` after calling `next()`; only calling next() will not stop execution of the current function.

Replace

`if(req.query.action !== 'view') { next(); };`

with

`if(req.query.action !== 'view') { next(); return;};`

Comment: Well now, that makes a lot of sense. Coming from C for mcu's I've been feeling js is almost a mind reader, making me think weirdly in terms of execution and scope. Anyhow, thanks man!